# Why was my question about logging into GitHub using cmd set "on hold"?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I recently asked the following question:

[How do I log into github via cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494247/how-do-i-log-into-github-via-cmd)

I don't understand and no one has got back to me in quite a while. I need this sorted quickly. I don't know what people need here; it's as basic as asking how to find something on a certain website. What is so hard to understand here?

Comment: Your frustration shows both in your SO question and your MSO question. That alone can be enough to turn people away from your questions.

Comment: @Cray: "*I need this sorted quickly.*" Well, that's not what we're here for. This isn't a help desk, where you should expect problems to be "sorted quickly" or whatever. If you need to resolve a problem quickly, then SO is not the place. We resolve problems on our own timescale, to create useful knowledge for future people.

Comment: Seems like you're taking this way too much to heart. But what am I supposed to do? I have asked my question and addressed the issue. Even presented the error, as requested. It's really simple. But instead the question is treated as if I'm making trouble and everything is too vague.

Am I supposed to express a simple issue in a complex manner that may make even less sense just because?

In my experience, when searching for answers and reading through them here, they have been very hard to understand precisely because of unnecessary complexity for a simple solution.

Comment: No, you're supposed to ask questions clearly and concisely.  Assuming you know the solution doesn't do that.  Not adding the information required to actually help you also doesn't do that.  Remember, we can't read your mind, and we want to ensure anyone else that runs into this issue can also be helped by this question.  That means everything needed to solve the question needs to be a part of the question.  In general, being open to improvement and responding in a timely fashion can help others help you.

Answer (score 22):

> I need this sorted quickly.

Users are in no position to make demands about any kind of timing in the way their questions are answered, edited, considered or moderated. This is a free website, we are all willingly and freely giving our time and knowledge do that other humans can possibly learn, the *very least* you can do is not give that feeling of entitlement.

You are not owed an answer.

As for your question, there is an error message, very clear, that you seem to ignore. For all we know, you've made a typo or forgotten the protocol in your url. Typo, vague, or guesswork questions are off-topic, hence we close them.

From the comments on your question, I see this comment of yours:

> if you really need to see the error, this is it: remote: Repository not found. Fatal: repository 'github.com/[user name]/[project name]' not found With the [user name] and [project name] being specific to the directory of the project.

***Yes, we really need to see the error.***

An error message is the very first step in debugging whatever problem you will ever come across in programming. You should learn to read them, and take them seriously, and not discard them as noise. They are much, much more important than any "impression" or "feeling" of what is going on.

Comment: Regarding "I need this sorted quickly." I didn't think of it as a demand, but simply stating that it is something that I need fixing relatively quickly. You are free to ignore my questions and comments, so why make that a vocal point?

As for error debugging, I usually do provide error messages, but this seemed simple enough that I did not think it was worth the trouble. I knew what the situation was, all I needed was the command, or further guidance to what to do if there wasn't one. I wanted to ask a simple question, with provided context, expecting to may be get an answer just as simple.

Comment: @Cray: "*why make that a vocal point?*" Because you said it. If it didn't matter, you wouldn't have said it. Ergo, if you say it, then you think it's important enough to say. "*I knew what the situation was*" And yet, actual Git experts seem to believe that it is not the situation you think it is. This is why trying to out-think answerers to a problem you're having is not helpful. Don't decide for others what the necessary context and information is; provide *all* of the information and let them figure it out.

Comment: On top of that, I did provide the error, but the question was set "on hold" after I did this. There was no indication of why. Could it have been the case that the question was being reviewed before I added the comment with the error? I don't know how things work here exactly.

Comment: @Cray At this point, it would be more profitable for you to accept that the question needs to be improved and think on how to improve it, than to contest its closure.

Comment: @Cray _"I did provide the error, but the question was set "on hold" after I did this."_ But it seems that you did not edit the error into the actual question (it was later on added by another user). Since comments are not expected to contain important information about a question (they can be deleted at any time), the question should have been edited to contain it. At this point, it will just have to go through the standard question reopening procedures.

Answer (score 18):

Reasons why your question was closed:

1. Insufficient information about the cause of the problem.

   You provided a command line, but you didn't provide any of the configurations that would actually determine the specific meaning of that command. Similarly, you had to be prompted to add the error message, and even when you did so (not in the question, but in a comment), the message was *redacted*, culling out key pieces of information (namely, the URL you're trying to access).

   Why did you do this? Because you had already decided what the problem was: that your repo was private and thus you needed to provide login credentials. Therefore, the specifics of your configuration were, in your mind, irrelevant.

   Unfortunately, the less you understand a system, the less likely you are to be able to correctly diagnose a problem from a set of symptoms. If you're new to Git, then you shouldn't be deciding whether the problem is due to failed login or something else, not unless an error message or something specifically says, "hey, this failed to log in".
2. A general unwillingness to do some legwork on your own.

   Consider [the following comment from you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494247/how-do-i-log-into-github-via-cmd#comment95812750_54494247):

   > Also @konst I only now understood the context of what you meant with the "remote URL". Not useful to me at all without context.

   This was a response to [a comment posted 24 hours before yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494247/how-do-i-log-into-github-via-cmd#comment95794015_54494247), one that essentially asked for the information I was talking about from step 1. So in that 24 hours, you saw that term, but didn't understand it. You then failed to Google that term (or if you did, your GoogleFu is not strong, and you need to fix *that*), and thus you didn't find out what "remote URL" was until many other comments were posted.

   This is one example of a general unwillingness I sense towards finding solutions for yourself. You seem to consistently want us to *tell you* stuff, rather than make efforts to find that stuff out on your own.

   I don't know Git, but I do know Mercurial. And any time I'm not logged in and try to do something that requires login information, Mercurial prompts me for a username/password, whether from the command line or from TortoiseHg. Not only that, pretty much every Mercurial command line has the ability to explicitly specify login information with options.

   Now, maybe Git's documentation is terrible and difficult to read. Maybe Git uses a more complex system for logging in than Mercurial. Maybe there are a lot of things going on here that I don't know.

   However, nothing in your question indicates that you have looked into *any of this*. Thus, even if the problem cited in your question was the actual problem (which it probably isn't), your question is poorly researched.
3. The likely problem is just a typo.

   From what actual users of Git seem to be saying, the problem is just a mistyped URL. That's not a useful question for Stack Overflow, and thus it deserves to be closed.

   So even if you fix all of the above, it's probably still not an appropriate question.

Comment: I did actually search for this issue for a bit before resorting to asking here, I just assumed that the issue was different and a bit more simple than it now seems to be. I look for solutions until I can't find them or don't know where to look, or have no idea what is going on anymore, which is exactly what is going on here, don't you think?

It can't be a url typo problem, I demonstrated it in the deleted question. And speaking of the question, the context of it is gone, so I guess it's going to be one hell of a mess for anyone who might get a similar issue as me and stumble upon this.

Comment: I've been discouraged enough to not proceed anymore about the issue here, so I think I'll ask about it on github forum (and for the record no, I did not know github had a forum before asking the first question regarding this issue, the thought never ocurred to me).